# Html - Wrong letters (sometimes)

Tags: html, wordpress

I have created a website with wordpress and i have a bulleted list on it as follows:

Pros

- realistic colors
- very sharp

The problem is *sometimes* (like each fifth time) when i load the page in Chrome, the letters of the word `Pros` are wrong like `Qspt`. See the following picture:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Post the URL associated

Comment: There isn't enough info here to give a conclusive answer. How do you get rid of the problem?

Comment: @ManojKumar I did not want to post the url as it could be seen as spam. The url is https://www.best-4k-monitor.com/dell-up2414q-test/

Comment: @SRing When I refresh using F5, the text is sometimes wrong and sometimes it everything is right. *It seems to occur mainly when I hit Strg+F5 (load without cache)*

Comment: I tried refreshing several times either using Chrome and Firefox both latest versions, and it works fine.

Comment: It's something to do with your Javascript. The line is happens on seems to do something with emojis? Maybe a UTF encoding issue?

Comment: @Steve Might be. When I disable Javascript it works fine. I don't think I have scripts included for emojis though.

Comment: @Dennis It was hard to tell because it was all minified. But there's definitely something going on with the javascript. You'll have to try and look through the unminified JS to see if it's set anywhere.

Comment: @Steve I just used "Disable Emojis" plugin to remove the emoji Javascript.  Problem persists, but I will look into the other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hints got me on the right path. It was a javascript issue in '[jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)':

```
if ($('.review-wrapper').length) {
    $('.review-wrapper').appear().on('appear', function(event) {
      // this element is now inside browser viewport
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasClass('delay-animation')) {
          $this.removeClass('delay-animation');         
      }
    });
    $.force_appear(); // if it's right there on document.ready
}
```

It seems that `force_appear` was responsible for the wrong letters. So I am using `force_process` option now instead:

```
if ($('.review-wrapper').length) {
    $('.review-wrapper').appear({force_process: true}).on('appear', function(event) {
      // this element is now inside browser viewport
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasClass('delay-animation')) {
          $this.removeClass('delay-animation');         
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was it in force_appear that changed the letters?

Comment: @Steve Sorry I did not have the time to investigate further. When I find something out I will let you now.